# I have to create windows application which open source database can i use?

Tags: database

I have to create windows application in C# **which open source database can i use** . It will be a single user application on desktop or laptop. Database needs to be installed on client machine only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project I used SQL Lite with great success. You have to install a C# adapter and I've included an article to help you through it.

Here is the main website:

https://www.sqlite.org/

Link to help you use SQL Lite for your project.

http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/